# Google App Engine Django Standard Environment: Error: Server Error

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy the most simple Django 1.10.5 project into Google App Engine and am completely stumped.

Upon running `gcloud app deploy` I am getting the following error when navigating to `/`...

[image]

This is the file structure of my app...

[image]

This is my `.yaml` file...

[image]

This is my `appengine_config.py` file...

[image]

I am also getting the following errors in Google Dev Tools `network` tab...

[image]

I am pretty certain the problem lies within my `app.yaml` file and am very unclear as to what `url` and `handler` are doing in this code. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: please don't post text as images, instead copy and paste the text into your post and format it accordingly

Comment: Where is your lib folder which should basically contain the Django module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be quite far off from getting your django based app running on GAE. For example you're missing the `lib` dir where your version of django should be installed. You may want to go through [Running Django on App Engine standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine)

Comment: that did it. Already went through that tutorial and was trying to do it on my own with my own app.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of GAE log page and search text "raise". If you see something like "sqlite3", the problem might be caused by the default content of DATABASES section in settings.py file. Commenting out this DATABASES section solved my problem("Error: Server Error" only when deployed to GAE; working fine locally).